# I can't install pyaudio

Tags: python

```
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [9 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
      copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9  
      running build_ext
      building '_portaudio' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]
  

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.


ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for pyaudio did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [11 lines of output]
      running install
      C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.    
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
      copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
      running build_ext
      building '_portaudio' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pyaudio

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: There's a C/C++ component to the package and pip is trying to build it.  The error tells you what you're missing: `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools"`.

Comment: install from prebuilt wheel

Answer (score 1):

`enter code here`1. `pip install pipwin`
2. `pipwin install pyaudio`